# Double setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, intervals

When my AJAX call is completed I need to call `setInterval`, but when two AJAX calls are made it also calls `setInterval` twice. How can I stop the previous `setInterval`?

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
  $(".iframeFake").load(function () {
    var islem = setInterval(function () {
       $('.iframeFake').each(function (event) {
         console.log(1);
       }, 1000);
   });
});
```

In chrome console in first post i get 1 per second - but after second post i get double 1 per second. Where is my problem?

Comment: Please post some code or this will be closed after heavy down voting

Comment: Without seeing any code, the best we can do is point you to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) and hope you figure the rest out on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var islem;
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(".iframeFake").load(function () {
        clearInterval(islem);
        islem = setInterval(function () {
            $('.iframeFake').each(function (event) {
                console.log(1);
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

If you want to maintain that there is always one interval, store the variable at a higher scope, and cancel before you create to stop any lingering intervals.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/s55SS/) of the principle in action

Comment: did you both move the var and cancel?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I don't believe you. If the variable is above the function scope, and you cancel before declaring, its not possible to have more than one interval.

Comment: if you don't believe i can give you teamviewer to see.

Comment: What changed? Can you post the code in its final form?